# AngulsrJS $filter orderBy an an array key with @ symbol

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

```
{
    "@odata.count": 52,
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 0.58868027,
            "LastDirSyncTime": "2015-02-27T08:22:22+00:00"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.58868029,
            "LastDirSyncTime": "2015-03-27T08:22:22+00:00"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.60868029,
            "LastDirSyncTime": "2014-03-27T08:22:22+00:00"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.58861029,
            "LastDirSyncTime": "2014-03-27T08:22:22+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the above json return that I want to `orderBy` I've used

`var newdata = $filter('orderBy')(data, '@search.score');`

But it returns `Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [@] in expression [@search.score].`

Is there a way to get my results to orderBy the `@search.score` key?

Answer (score 0):

Parse your object and remove '@search' from '@search.score'

```
$scope.abc= [
{
  "score": 0.58,
  "LastDirSyncTime": "2015-02-27T08:22:22+00:00"
},
{
  "score": 0.59,
  "LastDirSyncTime": "2015-03-27T08:22:22+00:00"
},
{
  "score": 0.60,
  "LastDirSyncTime": "2014-03-27T08:22:22+00:00"
},
{
  "score": 0.52,
  "LastDirSyncTime": "2014-03-27T08:22:22+00:00"
}
];
```

and then u can just use 'orderBy' (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Score</th>
    <th>LastDirSyncTime</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="a in abc | orderBy:'score'">
    <td>{{a.score}}</td>
    <td>{{a.LastDirSyncTime}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newdata = $filter('orderBy')(data, '"@search.score"');
```

`orderBy` expects an expression and `@search.score` isn't recognized as valid one. Apart from the `@` it also contains a `.` that would be interpreted differently than you'd expect.

`"@search.score"` on the other hand is a valid constant string expression that is interpreted as property name.

I'd refrain from using dots in property names.